# How do I change the value of a variable using a dynamic pointer and a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

How do I change the value of a variable using a dynamic pointer or a smart pointer ?

```
int a=5;
int *b= new int(a);
*b=10;

cout<< a;
```

The output is 5. Is it possible for me to change the value of "a" using a dynamic or smart pointer?

Comment: What? `int *b = &a`?

Comment: It's a dynamic pointer.

Comment: Regarding OP's comment on question and answers, his expectation as not the one you could guess from the question. I'm voting to close it as _unclear what's you're asking_.

Comment: @Slava There's absolutely not need to be rude.

Comment: `dynamic*` is a dynamic pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a dynamic pointer that points to an `int` allocated in *automatic* memory. If you would like to work with dynamic pointers, you can use [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), like this:

```
shared_ptr<int> a { new int(5) };
cout<< *a << endl;
shared_ptr<int> b { a };
*b = 10;
cout << *a << endl;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/eX5ORK)

Answer (score 4):

```
int *b = new int(a);
```

allocates a new `int` taking the same *value* as `a`. To point to `a`, just use

```
int *b = &a;
```

I don't know why you mention smart pointers here, they have no relevance. They are usually used for managing the lifetime of allocated memory, which you shouldn't be doing.

You can't learn C++ effectively by guesswork and experimentation. I suggest you [pick up a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1171191).

Comment: Can you please answer that?

Comment: @BriefcaseJoe please edit your question, you said "or," not "and."

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, but the line `int *b = new int(a);` is taking a *value* copy of `a`.

What's wrong with `int* b = &a;`?

Then you can manipulate `a` by dereferencing `b`.

Smart pointers will not help you here as they are concerned with managing the lifetime of something allocated with `new`. *Your* pointer is pointing to a variable with automatic storage duration.